# Play sound and start vibration on animation repeat

Tags: android, animation, audio, android-vibration

I want to repeat sound and vibration with the repeat of an animation. I've created a mediaplayer object and starting it in `onAnimationRepeat`

```
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mpDot.start();
    vibrator.vibrate(40L);


}
```

But nothing is happening. Neither the sound is repeating nor the vibration also
`onAnimationStart` I've called `mpDot.start()` too... So whenever animation is started sound also starts and stops with it. But it doesn't repeat. Why?

Can anybody help.

Comment: if(acceptAnswers){ void startVibration();}

Comment: so i checked the code and i dont know why the onAnimationRepeat is not working.....onAnimationStart is working, onAnimationEnd is working bt repeat is not...

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, i think they have a bug or something, thats what has been posted here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13397

Comment: yeah its a bug in android api...it doesnt listens to onAnimationrepeat

Comment: So what can i do? How can i sync Sound with Animation?